# ADF CI/CD How to release to higher environment only items that are tested

Tags: azure-data-factory, cicd

According to Microsoft. ADF will create the adf_publish branch that contain the ARM template. If I have 3 environment: DEV, UAT and PROD. And 2 items of work: A and B. Both of them are developed in DEV and merged to master and published afterward.

From adf_publish I will then deploy the UAT for testing purposes. What if item A is passed the UAT, B is not and I only want to deploy item A into next PROD release. Do I have to create another branch from DEV to eliminate B, merge to master and re-deploy to DEV/UAT/PROD again? Please view this
[Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gvPT.png).

Answer (score 0):

In case of Azure data factory, release pipeline will take ARM templates from `adf_publish` branch and then deploy them directly in to different environments. ARM templates will be generated in `adf_publish` branch when you actually publish changes to DEV ADF after your PR.

Hence, it will good if you can plan to execute test cases of UAT also on feature branches itself so that any specific branch related changes of passing your test case then you can avoid PR for that specific branch.